# How do I group NAICS Industry codes under one broader two digit subgroup to get the total # of loans within that one industry in Python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset that has a variable, NAICS Industry, represented by a 6 digit #, I want to get this # narrowed down to the first two digits, so I can combine industries for a broader view.  After I get the industry # narrowed down to two digits instead of 6; I want to use value counts to count the total # of loans that fall within that NAICS industry code.  Can someone please help.  I have attached pictures for reference.

[Reference of NAICS Industry codes; as you can see some of the codes have the same first two digits; I want to group these codes under one broader subgroup to get the total # of loans within that one industry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyzZv.png)

Comment: A clarification question: will a NAICS code in your dataset ever have less than six digits, and/or leading zero digits?

Comment: @nanofarad no; NAICS codes will have 6 digits in my dataset.

Comment: "I have attached pictures for reference." [Please do not do this for simple text data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach depends on the data type of the NAICS data (which I can't tell from the screenshot alone) and assumptions about the number of digits.

Assuming that the dataset contains *only* six-digit NAICS codes in integer format (that is, `df['NAICS'].dtype` is `int64` or similar), the first two digits can be obtained by dividing the NAICS code by 10000 using integer division:

```
df['NAICS_sector'] = df['NAICS'] // 10000
```

Note that you must use `//` (integer division) and not `/` (floating-point division).

If the NAICS codes are in the dataframe in string format (that is, `df['NAICS'].dtype` says `object`), you can use string manipulation instead:

```
df['NAICS_sector'] = df['NAICS'].str.slice(stop=2)
```

Setting `stop=2` means that the first two characters are returned from each entry. The parameters of the `slice` method are explained in the [official Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html).

Finally, if your dataset contains integers but you cannot guarantee they all have the same length, you'll want to use string manipulation anyway,
by converting the column to a string and then using the second sample.

After all this is done, you can group using the new `NAICS_sector` column.

Comment: Thank you so much; I hope to be just as great as you one day!!  You solved this frustrating problem for me in no time; I appreciate it.  Have a great day!  :)  Btw, the data type was int64, so the first solution worked great.  Thanks again.